# Unable to upgrade to a Dynatrace enabled apk

Tags: android, instrumentation, android-instrumentation, dynatrace, android-update-app

I have used the auto-instrumentor command on my Android apk file.

```
auto-instrumentor.cmd apk <apk file> prop <APK-Instr.properties>
```

It generated three new files:

1. unsigned
2. signed
3. final

Now I am able to use my app when I do a fresh install.

But if I try to upgrade an earlier build to this Dynatrace enabled version, it always gives me a message

```
App Not Installed.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not using the original certificates to sign the apk you will not be able to install the instrumented app over the already existing once. The only option you have is to uninstall the original app and install the instrumented app.

If you have the original certificates you need to take the following steps:

1. take the unsigned apk and instrument the apk
2. sign the apk
3. zip align the apk

For more information please take a look at the [Android Auto-Instrumentation documentation](https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/DOCDT62/Auto-Instrumentation+for+Android)